# Add a window event listener to WebView and call a Java function

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm displaying a webpage in my Android app using a `WebView`, this webpage triggers a window message event and gives some data through that event. I need to access the data from the message event.

To achieve this, I'm adding the JavaScript event listener by using `evaluateJavascript()` method and trying to call a Java function from the JavaScript using `addJavascriptInterface()`.

My Code so far:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(this), "Android");
    
        webView.evaluateJavascript("window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {Android.logData('Test String')})", null);
    
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/mypage");
    
        setContentView(webView);
    }
    
    private class JsObject {
        Context context;
    
        JsObject(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void logData(String s) {
            Log.v("EEE", s);
        }
    }
    
}
```

But the event handler is not getting called. I'm not sure whether this is the right approach. Please help. TIA.

Comment: @RyanMentley I'm trying to add an event handler to the `WebView` to handle the window message event. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm going to assume "not working" means "the Java function is, for whatever reason, not getting called" - I answered based on my best guess there

Comment: @RyanMentley Thanks. That's the case. The event handler is not triggering, so the Java function is not getting called. I will edit the question.

Comment: Hopefully my answer helps - I think it should, but it might depend on the JavaScript.

Comment: I didn't find any way to capture the window event in Android. If you're trying to send data from your website running in `WebView` to android and you can edit the site [this answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608159/5780058)

Comment: Hi @AjaySivan I am also facing the same issue. Have you got the solution? If yes, then please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of your `loadUrl` and `evaluateJavascript` calls.  The `loadUrl` is resetting that state.  Note: this may require changing the code on the page to avoid a race condition triggering the message.

From the [`evaluateJavascript` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%2520android.webkit.ValueCallback%253Cjava.lang.String%253E)):

> global variables and functions defined before calling loadUrl(java.lang.String) will not exist in the loaded page

Comment: Still, the event handler is not getting called. Is there anything else wrong in my code? Or is there any other way to add an event handler?

Comment: Hmm.  Can you tell if the JavaScript function is getting called?  or if there are any JavaScript errors?  Try logging console messages: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage(android.webkit.ConsoleMessage)

Comment: And if you do `console.log("foo");` in JavaScript, that shows up to confirm the logging works?

Comment: I tried adding a log message inside the `addEventHandler()` callback function, that didn't work. I have also tried passing `"(function(){console.log("Working")})()"` to `evaluateJavascript`. That logged the message "Working".

Comment: In that case, it's impossible to debug without seeing the calling code (also I'm not a JavaScript expert so my expertise on that side of it may be less useful)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for sharing your suggestions.