# How to add window message event Listener - Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

How to add an event listener to handle `window` **message** event in a `WebView`. I have tried this,

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("window.addEventListener('message', function (e) { Android.logData('HELLO')});", null);
```

But it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exploring I didn't find any way to get data from the website running in `WebView` to the app without adding any code to in the website. And finally, I decided to make the necessary changes on my website as well. And this is how I did it:

**In App**

Created a class

```
private class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void shareData(String data) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, data);
    }
}
```

Add an instance of the new class as Javascript Interface to the `WebView` with a name

```
ssWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "Android");
```

This instance will be added to the `window` object of the `WebView` as `Android`(name, the second argument of the above function)

**In Website**

In the website to share data

```
window.Android && window.Android.shareData("This is the data from website");
```